# SQL Server - Select inserted rows in a table, inside THE SAME transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I need confirmation for one "tricky" question.
I am in a transaction, in which i insert some rows in a table.
   After that, querying the same table, and based on the results, i insert in another table.

My question is: Will the inserted rows in the first table be visible when inserting in the second table? (I need the inserted rows to be visible).

My first Insert Is :

```
INSERT INTO BioUsers Select NewId(),A.BadgeNr,GetDate(),A.PersNr
        FROM (
            SELECT CB.Persnr,C.BadgeNr FROM CurBioDistribution CB 
                INNER JOIN CUR C ON C.PersNr = CB.PersNr 
                WHERE 
                    CB.[Type] = 1 
                    AND CB.GroupNr = @Nr 
                    AND CB.PersNr IN (SELECT PersNr FROM CurBioDistribution WHERE GroupNr = @Nr) 
                    EXCEPT (SELECT PersNr, BadgeId as BadgeNr FROM BioUsers)
            ) A
```

I want To insert all the BioUserID's in the first table in another table, which contains the field `BioUserID`, but only if they are not already in it. So when select from the first one, i want to get the inserted rows too.

PS: I searched for this problem, but i could only find answers about this issue when multiple transaction (from different clients) are involved.

Comment: Some sample code and more details of what you have already tried  will help you get an answer.

Comment: Done: Anyway It was just a question, I was not asking on how to do it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If both inserts are in the same transaction, then yes. 
If not then you are in what you described as a multi-user scenario. Multi user is infact misleading, multi transaction would be more correct.

Comment: Thank You. It seemed like an obvious answer, but I just wanted to be sure, because I don't want things to go wrong here at work because of me:) Have a nice day!